# How to handle double "~" in Python path?

Tags: python, path

The user input a path, so in Unix, he/she may enter `~/../../~`. And I want Python to convert that to a absolute path. How to do that? The `os.path.expanduser()` can only expand the first `~`, but not the following ones `~`

So you will only get `os.path.expanduser(~/../../~)` = `/Users/somebody/../../~`

Thanks

Comment: Bash also only expands  `~` if it's the first character in the path, just like `os.path.expanduser()`

Comment: @ThierryLathuille great. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @ThierryLathuille don't think it as a stupid question though.

Answer (score 1):

That's how tilde expansion is *supposed* to work. Even the shell wouldn't expand the second `~`; tilde expansion only happens at the front of a path. See the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01) or the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html).

`os.path.expanduser` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

See user2357112's answer; they are by no means wrong. However, if you *really* insist on having it done this way:

```
import os

path = '~/foo/bar/~'
home_path = os.path.expanduser('~')

path = path.replace("~", home_path.lstrip('/')
```